# how to change the existing managerObject in managerObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I think the answer is very simple, maybe I'm missing something important! I can insert a new object, I can remove an object from managerObjectContext, I can access the object via its ID, but I can not understand how I can change it!

my code is very simple:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
return [(CalcAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] managedObjectContext];}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Materials"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES]];

list = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

[tbl reloadData];}
```

i pass data to another ViewController

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MatListToDetailSegue"]) {
    MaterialsDetailViewController *detailMaterial = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailMaterial.material = [list objectAtIndex:tbl.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
    detailMaterial.managedObjectId = [[list objectAtIndex:tbl.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] objectID];
}
```

and i want to save this managedObject in managedObjectContext and commit the managedObjectContext , but i don't have any changes in SQLite file!

```
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender {

material.matName = editMaterialName.text;
material.matWidth = [NSNumber numberWithInt:300];
material.matPrice = [NSNumber numberWithInt:300];

[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Materials''**

wow! thank you vary mach for the answers! i solved the problem.

Al i needed to: delete this from method -(IBAction)saveBtn

```
material = (Materials *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Materials" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

and change [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
}
```

Thanks for advance for your reply!!!

Comment: At first, you're not checking return value of `-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` which is `BOOL`. If it returns `NO`, nothing was saved. Also you're not retrieving error in case when it returns `NO`. Fix it and come later with error message.

Comment: thank you, i fix it and now i have error when i call the method -(IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Materials''

Comment: create a "find" method that will fetch/create a new material object from db, modify that object and save to it's own context.

Comment: Are you sure you have an entity that is called Materials? Because that is what the exception is telling you is wrong.

Comment: thank you , i solved the problem ... i had the wrong line: material = (Materials *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Materials" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

Comment: Wait, into your `Material` object you are assigning an instance of `NSEntityDescription`. I am almost certain that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, into your `Material` object you are assigning an instance of `NSEntityDescription`. I am almost certain that is not what you want.

That is why you are crashing. When Core Data is saving, it is trying to save your `Material` object (expecting it to be a subclass of `NSManagedObject`), but instead you have a `NSEntityDescription` in that memory space.

Also, you are somewhere using both `Materials` and somewhere `Material`. Can't that also be a problem?